# How do I clone over HTTP a repository that has no info/refs?

Tags: git, http, git-clone

Given a repository served over HTTP whose owner forgot to `chmod +x hooks/post-update`, is there a workaround for cloning it?

I tried running `wget --mirror url`, but rather than fetching the subtree only, it tried to mirror the entire site—which I assume happened due to the parent-directory links in the autogenerated `index.html` resources.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I'm curious - Why is the post-update hook required to clone? (what does that have to do with having info/refs?) And how are there no refs at all? All the branches got deleted?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the source code to build and don't really need the repo, try adding --no-parent to wget. That should limit wget to the subtree.

Apart from that, email the person who runs the repository and ask them to fix it.

Comment: --no-parent will download the repo so that you can work with it on your computer.  You'll be able to clone, etc from that directory after that.